# GridView to Excel ASPX in SharePoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, datagridview, export-to-excel

I have an ASPX file which I am running in SharePoint that has a GridView which I am attempting to export into an excel spreadsheet.  I know the code I have for the export is correct; however, I am getting this error:

```
RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();
```

I have done some research and have found a solution, which might work with normal ASPX pages created in VS with a CS code behind class, which is setting the EnableEventValidation to false, and I am getting a Parser error when I attempt to use this solution on my ASPX page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation = "false"%>
```

Is there any other way to allow this, or any other workaround to my problem using just the ASPX page without the code behind?  All of my C# code is within the head and has to be in order for me to run it in my SharePoint environment.  12 hive storage of the CS class is not an option for me.  Also,  I am not wanting to change anything in my web.config folder if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try creating it as a Web Part - this is the more common approach for this type of scenario in SharePoint.

In SharePoint, all customized pages are run through the Safe Mode Parser which prohibits inline code. Also, this parser does not allow adding controls to pages which have not been marked as "safe".

To get around your issue, you might want to look at "Application Pages" which are added to the \LAYOUTS directory. They reference the master page and can have inline code, but they can't be customized. They are compiled into a single assembly DLL:

[Creating an Application Page in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418732%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: You are correct, but This is not going to be an option for me.  My customer is not wanting this to be in a web part. This is one small part of a large project.  Also, I have had to adjust my web.config file to allow code blocks for this project as well.  I would not be able to put this into a web part if I wanted to.  I think I am just going to have to settle with a CSV File.  Thanks for the responce.

Comment: No prob. Note that a Web Part can be made to "not look like a Web Part" ;-)